# How to add existing named_scope to anonymous scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, named-scope

I have a model:

```
class Shirt < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :red, :conditions => { :color => 'red' }
  named_scope :blue, :conditions => { :color => 'blue' }
  named_scope :xl,  :conditions => { :size  => 'xl'  }
end
```

I forgot, how to easy add named scope to existing anonymous scope:

```
scope = Shirt.scoped({})
#and how to add ie. :red to scope?
```

Answer (score 1):

`Shirt.scoped({}).red` ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with the following code:

```
named_scope :colour, lambda { |colour_id| {:conditions => ["colour_id = ?", colour_id])}}
```

You can chain named scopes:

```
Shirt.red.xl
```

Comment: You posted, how to create name scope, but I would like to know how to add existing scope to anonymous scope.

Comment: Sorry - misunderstood. Do you mean as in: Shirt.scoped({}).red.xl